# Custom block disable caching?

Tags: 8, entities, blocks, caching

I've created a custom module to show On This Days in a block but they are not changing each day until I flush the caches.

I call the entity:

```
public function build() {
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
    $query->condition('status', 1);
    $query->condition('type', 'on_this_day');
    $query->condition('field_filter_date', '-' . date("m-d"), 'CONTAINS');
    $entity_ids = $query->execute();
```

...

and then return from the build function like this:

```
return array(
        '#markup' => $content,
        '#cache' => array(
            'max-age' => 0,
        ),
```

Any ideas?
I'm thinking entity cache or something but I'm quite new to this and not too sure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use max-age](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191458/how-to-use-max-age)

Comment: Hi, I am using that but I suspect that it's the entities caching or something?

Answer (score 0):

The way to invalid the Cache in a Block is with

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }
```

This comes from BlockBase

Comment: Thanks, I do have this in the code but no luck I'm afraid.